# When I move files in a docker container why does ls show this output?

Tags: docker

I wanted to test something by moving some jar files with `mv -f spring* ~` in my docker container and restarting it, however when I did so and I executed `ls -l` in the directory I got output as shown below

```
-rw-r--r--. 12 cgri root   594033 Apr  4 12:33 snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
???????????  ? ?    ?           ?            ? spring-oxm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 12 cgri root   365288 Apr  4 12:32 ssl-config-core_2.11-0.2.1.jar
```

Why are these remnants of the files left here and what are the implications?

Answer (score 2):

The question marks in the ls output usually indicate that it has the read permission but not x (search). You shouldn't e able to `stat` it either.

Try to exec to container using `-u root`

Comment: same issue with `docker exec -u root -it sample bash`

Comment: How do you move the files? If you use a docker file, can you share it?

Comment: I can't share the container, but I logged onto the container and executed `mv -f spring* ~` as root
I also tried just deleting the files with `docker exec sample rm -rf /usr/local/sample/lib/spring*` and got the same result